# What does the phrase "starter pack" mean in the context of programming?

Tags: meaning, usage

Source: http://rhuno.com/flashblog/2013/12/08/video-tutorial-tetris-with-html5-and-js/

> In this tutorial you will learn how to create a simple Tetris clone using HTML5 and Javascript. In addition to keyboard control, you will implement touch interaction so that the game can be played on mobile devices such as the iPhone and Android phones.
>   It's a doozy, so you may want to break it up into multiple viewing sessions or make sure you've got time to spare.
>   You can download the **starter pack** to follow along, or download the completed project.

I looked up the word in Wikipedia but I'm still not sure what it means in this context.

Comment: Just download it and see what's inside that :) I think they have only provided Images and some basic files for that tutorial to help you focus on the main concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *starter pack* is, as its name suggests, a pack of supplies intended to help a "starter" - someone new to this kind of work - get started.

For instance, an *engineer's starter kit* may come with some wires, LEDS, transistors, and everything else you need to get started with a basic engineering project.

A *kitchen starter kit* would come with several necessary kitchen equipment like: spoons, forks, knives, cutting board, rolling pin, bowls, plates, and so on.

The idea of a *starter pack* or *starter kit* is that you only need some basic equipment/tools/materials to get "started" on something.

> in the context of programming?

A starter pack for programming is known as an SDK (Software Development Kit).  The SDK will usually come with demos and documentation.  Everything after that would be considered a plugin, an add-on, a library, et cetera.

Comment: Your definitions of *starter pack* are on the mark, but it's wrong to equate that term with *SDK*, which is [something else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit). A programming starter kit might contain an SDK, but not necessarily and not vice versa. An SDK is a set of (often minimal) tools and maybe some instructions designed to work with a specific product or service; a starter kit contains tools, instructions, raw materials, a few small working samples, etc, and is much more general. An SDK will require other things to produce a working product, but a starter kit will not.

Comment: But your definition of an SDK is the exact definition of a starter park.  Yes, an SDK can require a particular OS, or kernel, knowledge of the programming language and so on; much like how a kitchen starter park will require you have a kitchen.

Comment: Not to get too far off topic, but a starter pack in the context of the OP is about getting started with a particular development project for learning purposes, so it may have sample code, image files, etc. It probably would *not* have the SDK - that is something that you would likely have to have already downloaded.